# a:hover in span tag, how to remove hover style

Tags: html, css, hover, stylesheet

```css
a:hover {
   text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>
     <span class="title1">
      title1
     </span>
    title2 is hover underline
    </a>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How to remove hover style only title1.

title1 is none underline and title is underline;

Answer (score 4):

```css
a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}

.title1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

a:hover .title1 {
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
  <li><a><span class="title1">title1</span>title2 is hover underline</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pseudo element with :before

```css
a {
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    position: relative;
}
a:hover:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width:85%;
    height: 1px;
    left:18%;
    bottom: 0;   
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
  <li><a><span class="title1">title1</span>title2 is hover underline</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to this link:https://jsfiddle.net/17d80ym3/12/
```

This also give the correct results

Answer (score -1):

you are actually telling your link to have underlined text.
use a:hover{text-decoration:none;}
To style your span within a link you can go deeper:
a:hover span{color:blue;} for example.